# Why do I have an exception at navigator widget?

Tags: flutter, exception, navigation, widget

So I was trying to use the navigation widget to go from main page to about page but out of blue, I found and exception at navigator.push which says "Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.)"

It is saying that I haven't included the navigator but I clearly did and It also says that the navigator widget must be a descendant of another navigatoe widget which I don't understand what it means.

Also for the context, by editor isn't showing any syntax error even after running the code.

Here is the code:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.brown,
          title: const Text('Flutter Practice'),
        ),
        body: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Navigate'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (_) => AboutScreen(),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AboutScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const AboutScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        title: const Text('About'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxHua.png)

Comment: it's working with same code, you can try with another method like...

Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> AboutScreen()));

Answer (score 1):

you need to ensure that the `context` you're using is valid and comes from a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget. In your code, you're using the `context` from the `build` method of the `MyApp` widget. However, since `MyApp` is a `StatelessWidget` and is the root of your app, it doesn't have a `Navigator` ancestor.

To resolve this, you can wrap your `ElevatedButton` with a `Builder` widget. The `Builder` widget creates a new `BuildContext` that is a descendant of the nearest `Navigator` ancestor.

```
body: Builder(
          builder: (context) {
            return ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Navigate'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (_) => AboutScreen(),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          }
        ),
```

Comment: If it helps you kindly mark it as accepted answer for others also.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).